# ReactJS useState hook - asynchronous behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am building a page to list products.
So I've one input:file button to select multiple images and then I'm calling an API to upload that images on the server and displaying progress in UI with images.
Here's my code.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'

const Demo = () => {
    const [images, setImages] = useState([])

    const handleImages = async (e) => {
        let newArr = [...images]
        for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
            newArr = [
                ...newArr,
                {
                    src: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[i]),
                    img: e.target.files[i],
                    uploaded: 0,
                    completed: false,
                    _id: nanoid(5),
                },
            ]
        }
        setImages(newArr)
        await uploadImages(newArr)
    }

    const uploadProgress = (progress, arr, idx) => {
        let { total, loaded } = progress
        let inPercentage = Math.ceil((loaded * 100) / total)
        let imgs = [...arr]
        imgs[idx]['uploaded'] = inPercentage
        setImages([...imgs])
    }

    const uploadImages = async (imageArr) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < imageArr.length; i++) {
            let formData = new FormData()
            formData.append('img', imageArr[i].img)

            let result = await axios.post(
                `http://localhost:3001/api/demo`,
                formData,
                {
                    onUploadProgress: (progress) =>
                        uploadProgress(progress, imageArr, i),
                }
            )

            if (result?.data) {
                let imgs = [...imageArr]
                imgs[i]['completed'] = true
                setImages([...imgs])
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="file"
                multiple
                accept="image/*"
                onChange={handleImages}
            />
            <div>
                <div className="img-container" style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                    {images.length ? (
                        <>
                            {images.map((img) => (
                                <div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
                                    <img
                                        style={{
                                            width: '200px',
                                            height: 'auto',
                                            marginRight: '10px',
                                        }}
                                        src={img.src}
                                        alt="alt"
                                    />
                                    {!img.completed && (
                                        <div
                                            style={{
                                                background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
                                                padding: '4px',
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                top: '10px',
                                                left: '10px',
                                                color: 'white',
                                                borderRadius: '5px',
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            {img.uploaded}%
                                        </div>
                                    )}
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </>
                    ) : null}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Demo
```

As the useState is asynchronous, I can't directly pass that react state to my API handler.
So now the issue is, suppose I'm selecting 3 images to upload, and before the execution of my "uploadImages" function completes, I try to select other images to upload, It's not working as expected and I know the reason why it's not working the way intend to. But don't know the solution.

Issue:
suppose, the user first tries to upload 3 images. the first instance of "uploadImages" will begin its execution with parameter newArr which would have 3 images and we're setting it to react-state "images".
But now when the user tries to upload other images before letting the first ones finish, another instance of "uploadImages" will begin its execution and now in newArr parameter, it would have an array of newly added images and this method will try to set state "images".

Now I don't know how can I handle this.
[Preview](https://youtu.be/SVpO2KH0sjM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems.

1. Each time `uploadProgress` is run, it's using the images array that was passed to it by the `uploadImages` function. In other words, if you start uploading image A, you trigger an instance of `uploadProgress` running with `imageArr = [A]`. If you add image B, you trigger another separate instance of uploadProgress running with `imageArr = [A,B]`. Since you're setting state using those separate `imageArr`s in `uploadProgress`, the `images` state swaps from being the first array to the second array and back. (You can see this if you log from inside `uploadProgress`.)

```js
    const uploadProgress = (progress, arr, idx) => {
        let { total, loaded } = progress
        let inPercentage = Math.ceil((loaded * 100) / total)
        let imgs = [...arr]
        console.log(imgs.length) // will toggle between 1 and 2 
        imgs[idx]['uploaded'] = inPercentage
        setImages([...imgs])
    }
```

As others have said, you can solve this by using the functional setState pattern.

```
    const uploadProgress = (progress, idx) => {
        let { total, loaded } = progress
        let inPercentage = Math.ceil((loaded * 100) / total)
        setImages(arr => {
          let imgs = [...arr]
          imgs[idx]['uploaded'] = inPercentage
          return imgs
        })
    }
```

2. Second, each time you trigger `uploadImages` it starts the upload for every image, cumulatively. That means if you upload image A, wait a second, then add image B, it'll start uploading image A again and you'll end up with two different upload of image A. If you then were to add image C, you'd get three copies of image A, two copies of image B, and one of image C. You can solve this by preventing upload of images that have progress value or add a new property that indicates the image upload process has been started already.

```js
const uploadImages = async (imageArr) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < imageArr.length; i++) {
    if (imageArr[i].progress === 0) { // don't upload images that have already started
```

Comment: Yes @MynockSpit, that's causing the issue and I knew, 2 instance of upload images method are running simultaneously and trying to update setImages with different arr that I've been passed while calling an API. Thanks for your suggestion, I'll try!

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the already saved images with the setState callback. Which will pass the current images as a parameter:

```
setImages(prevImages => { // These are you already saved images
        let newArr = [...prevImages]
        for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
            newArr = [
                ...newArr,
                {
                    src: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[i]),
                    img: e.target.files[i],
                    uploaded: 0,
                    completed: false,
                    _id: nanoid(5),
                },
            ]
        }
        setImages(newArr)
        uploadImages(newArr)
})
```

The same needs to be done in the progress function.

Comment: I am already storing copy of current "images" state in newArr variable before appending newly added images at line number 7 in my code. But still I'll try your solution, thanks

Comment: But the `images` are only the images at the time of the api call. If you update those while the api call is executed, the new images are saved within the useState, but images object that you are refering to in line 7 are still the previous images from the time when the api was called. To access the current/newly saved images, you need to use the callback setImages( prev => ...), with prev being really the images from the latest save.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you rely on the `index` when updating the images objects inside the state. Can you try my proposal? It is a solution that uses the `_id` you have defined instead of the `index`.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'

const Demo = () => {
    const [images, setImages] = useState([])

    const findImageObj = (id) => images.find(({ _id }) => _id === id)

    const handleImages = async (e) => {
        let newArr = [...images]
        for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
            newArr = [
                ...newArr,
                {
                    src: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[i]),
                    img: e.target.files[i],
                    uploaded: 0,
                    completed: false,
                    _id: nanoid(5),
                },
            ]
        }
        setImages(newArr)
        await uploadImages(newArr)
    }

    const uploadProgress = (progress, arr, id) => {
        let { total, loaded } = progress
        let inPercentage = Math.ceil((loaded * 100) / total)
        const img = findImageObj(id)
        if(img) {
            let imgs = [...arr]
            img['uploaded'] = inPercentage
            setImages([...imgs])
        }
    }

    const uploadImages = async (imageArr) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < imageArr.length; i++) {
            let formData = new FormData()
            formData.append('img', imageArr[i].img)

            let result = await axios.post(
                `http://localhost:3001/api/demo`,
                formData,
                {
                    onUploadProgress: (progress) =>
                        uploadProgress(progress, imageArr, imageArr[i]._id),
                }
            )

            if (result?.data) {
                const img = findImageObj(imageArr[i]._id)
                if(img) {
                    let imgs = [...imageArr]
                    img['completed'] = true
                    setImages([...imgs])
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="file"
                multiple
                accept="image/*"
                onChange={handleImages}
            />
            <div>
                <div className="img-container" style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                    {images.length ? (
                        <>
                            {images.map((img) => (
                                <div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
                                    <img
                                        style={{
                                            width: '200px',
                                            height: 'auto',
                                            marginRight: '10px',
                                        }}
                                        src={img.src}
                                        alt="alt"
                                    />
                                    {!img.completed && (
                                        <div
                                            style={{
                                                background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
                                                padding: '4px',
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                top: '10px',
                                                left: '10px',
                                                color: 'white',
                                                borderRadius: '5px',
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            {img.uploaded}%
                                        </div>
                                    )}
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </>
                    ) : null}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Demo
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes is a asynchronous problem, try to access to your state via callback:

```
  const uploadProgress = (progress, idx) => {
        setImages((imagesState) => {
        let { total, loaded } = progress
        let inPercentage = Math.ceil((loaded * 100) / total)
        let imgs = [...imagesState]
        imgs[idx]['uploaded'] = inPercentage
        return [...imgs]
        })
    }


const uploadImages = async (imageArr) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < imageArr.length; i++) {
            let formData = new FormData()
            formData.append('img', imageArr[i].img)

            let result = await axios.post(
                `http://localhost:3001/api/demo`,
                formData,
                {
                    onUploadProgress: (progress) =>
                        uploadProgress(progress, i),
                }
            )

            if (result?.data) {
                setImages(imagesState => {
                let imgs = [...imagesState]
                imgs[i]['completed'] = true
                return [...imgs]
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All those who've answered this question, all are right, Thanks. I should access the state using setState callback. So I'm posting my updated code for other's reference.
Thanks

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'

const Demo = () => {
    const [images, setImages] = useState([])

    const findIdx = (arr, _id) => arr.findIndex((item) => item._id === _id)

    const handleImages = async (e) => {
        setImages((prevImgs) => {
            let newArr = [...prevImgs]
            for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
                newArr = [
                    ...newArr,
                    {
                        src: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[i]),
                        img: e.target.files[i],
                        uploaded: 0,
                        completed: false,
                        _id: nanoid(5),
                    },
                ]
            }
            uploadImages([...newArr])
            return newArr
        })
    }

    const uploadProgress = (progress, _id) => {
        let { total, loaded } = progress
        let inPercentage = Math.ceil((loaded * 100) / total)
        setImages((prevImgs) => {
            let imgs = [...prevImgs]
            let idx = findIdx(prevImgs, _id)
            imgs[idx]['uploaded'] = inPercentage
            return imgs
        })
    }

    const uploadImages = (imageArr) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < imageArr.length; i++) {
            if (imageArr[i].uploaded !== 0) continue

            let formData = new FormData()
            formData.append('img', imageArr[i].img)

            axios
                .post(`http://localhost:3001/api/demo`, formData, {
                    onUploadProgress: (progress) =>
                        uploadProgress(progress, imageArr[i]._id),
                })
                .then((result) => {
                    if (result?.data) {
                        setImages((prevImgs) => {
                            let imgs = [...prevImgs]
                            let idx = findIdx(prevImgs, imageArr[i]._id)
                            imgs[idx]['completed'] = true
                            return imgs
                        })
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => console.log('--> ERROR', err))
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="file"
                multiple
                accept="image/*"
                onChange={handleImages}
            />
            <div>
                <div className="img-container" style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                    {images.length ? (
                        <>
                            {images.map((img) => (
                                <div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
                                    <img
                                        style={{
                                            width: '200px',
                                            height: 'auto',
                                            marginRight: '10px',
                                        }}
                                        src={img.src}
                                        alt="alt"
                                    />
                                    {!img.completed && (
                                        <div
                                            style={{
                                                background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
                                                padding: '4px',
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                top: '10px',
                                                left: '10px',
                                                color: 'white',
                                                borderRadius: '5px',
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            {img.uploaded}%
                                        </div>
                                    )}
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </>
                    ) : null}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Demo
```